# Can I use ctrl-z to pause a script and then continue after rebooting my computer?

Tags: bash

I have a program than runs for about 18 hours but I need to do some things in Windows. I was wondering if there was a way to pause the script, reboot into Windows, and then reboot into Linux again and continue where I paused.

Comment: Ctrl+Z in a terminal freezes the current foreground process and returns you to the shell, where you can run other commands and resume the frozen process again later using the `fg` (foreground) or `bg` (background) command.

Comment: Do you mean do other things in the *terminal window* or actually reboot, and do things in another operating system (Window**s**)?

Comment: Assuming that your programme has no terminal input / output, you could run it in the background by putting a `&` after the command to run it. If you prefix it with `nice` it will run at a lower priority and less likely to get in the way of other stuff you are doing

Comment: I actually mean turning off the pc and using windows. then rebooting back to ubuntu and running the code where it paused.

Comment: @CésarLeonardoClementeLópez you can try hibernation, which should restore state, but without support from the script, this is tricky.

Comment: You can design the script to be interrupted and continue after interruption.

Answer (score 2):

Not with Ctrl+Z, no. That simply pauses execution but that can't survive rebooting. When you reboot, everything is shut down, including paused processes.

What might be possible is to *hibernate* instead of shutting down, then boot into Windows and, when finished, resume the hibernated Ubuntu. However, *I have not tried this and don't know if it would work*. If you have hibernation set up, try it and see.

Comment: When you turn your machine back on doesn't it just resume back into Ubuntu at the point it was hibernated? Sorry haven't used hibernate since the stone-age desktop days :D

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix it should, in theory, yes. But I haven't really used it either. I tried just now by hibernating, rebooting into Windows and rebooting back into my Linux but the hibernation didn't seem to have worked. I've never bothered with it though, and I'm not using Ubuntu, so it might work for the OP.

Comment: Some sort of assembler patch could be written for grub with option "resume hibernation'' and it could load swap file into RAM I guess...